# Linux create global command that immediately takes user to certain directory

Tags: linux, unix

When the user types in the command line `apps` and presses enter: I want it to immediately take the user to some directory, like `/var/foo/bar`.

At first I was thinking I could do this with a symlink, but I then realized that wouldn't work because it isn't global.

When I say the term "global", what I mean is that: no matter what directory the user is currently in: it will always move the user to the `/var/foo/bar` directory.

How might I be able to do this?

Comment: "Global"? *Exactly* what do you mean by that? You can put something in your OS's dotfiles (exactly where depends on the exact distro), but any user who doesn't want those dotfiles can avoid them if they choose to (or if they simply modify their `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, or similar to no longer honor whatever includes your operating system's `/etc/skel` contains).

Comment: You could even go so far as to have your PAM modules put an exported shell function into the environment for all users, but even then, they have to be using a shell that honors such functions before it'll work. Need to know exactly how robust you want it to be before we can really come up with an answer.

Comment: Ahh -- so this can work only for one user, not for every user on the system? That's trivial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an alias to the corresponding `cd` command:

```
alias apps="cd /var/foo/bar"
```

Comment: This worked for me.  I defined the alias in my `.bashrc` file.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are two main ways of achieving that.

### 1. Use a shell alias

Enter this into your shell:

```
$ alias apps="cd ~/applications"
```

From now on, on this particular shell session, typing `apps` and pressing enter will run `cd` and take you to `applications` (`~` is your home directory).

Note that here, **`apps` is not a program**, just an **alias**, a name that the shell recognizes and reinterprets.

To make the alias defined above permanent, you should add that line to your *shell profile*. This is a file, located at a known path, that runs every time you open a new shell. One of these files probably exist (`~` is your home directory):

```
~/.bashrc
~/.bash_profile
~/.profile
```

So, if you add the `alias` command at the bottom, it will be available on all new terminals.

### 2. Write a new program

***EDIT**: funny thing, this doesn't work for your case. A program cannot change the shell's current directory. It's still a nice summary of how to create a program, though. Use it for something else*

Creating new programs to accomplish specific tasks is pretty simple, but it takes some getting used to. We can do it in 3 steps.

1- Open a file named `apps` in your home directory, and put this in it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/applications # or whatever directory you want
```

The first line of the file is called a *hashbang*, and it signals that this program should be executed using `bash`, just like your command-line. The only other line is your bash command to change directory.

Save it in `~/apps`.

2- Make the file executable by running:

```
$ chmod +x ~/apps
```

3- Last, put this program in your `PATH`. The `PATH` is the shell's list of directories that contain programs. You already have some directories in your `PATH`:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
```

To make your program available to all users in the system, move it to `/usr/bin`:

```
$ sudo mv ~/apps /usr/bin/apps
```

If you can't `sudo`, you can still make this program available to all of your own terminals by adding a directory you control to the `PATH`.

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ PATH="$PATH:~/bin"
```

The second command extends the `PATH` to include `~/bin`. Like I explained for the `alias`, you can make this change permanent by putting it in your bash profile.

Now, move the program to your new `bin` directory:

```
$ mv ~/apps ~/bin/apps
```

You should be able to type `apps` and press enter to execute your program now.

Comment: #2 doesn't work. An external program can not change the shell's current directory.

Comment: HA! I was so busy writing the answer, I didn't even realize. Damn